# How to create a .docx file in a Sharepoint library programmatically and supply the content through a Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint list which is getting updated very often. I'm retrieving the list items using client object model. I want to write the list contents into a word file(.docx) and save it in a document library on the same Sharepoint site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice article on MSDN for your requirement. Please check it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742315.aspx). And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532473.aspx) blog article.